# Elasticsearch breaks on hyphens, dashes, spaces

Tags: angularjs, node.js, elasticsearch

I currently have my elasticsearch mappings set to analyzed by default, and I would like to keep the settings this way. However I've ran into situations where I try to query for ABC-123 or ABC 123 or ABC 123-1 and it breaks the elasticsearch query.

I'm working with an angularjs typeahead module using: https://github.com/jeff-collins/ment.io

The issue is when I start my query using the typeahead module whenever I hit a space or hyphen/dash it breaks the typeahead dropdown.

Here is the wildcard I have setup

```
router.get('/tagging', function(req, res) {
  switch (req.query.type) {
    case 'asset_list':
      client.search({
        index: 'core',
        type: 'assets',
        body: {
          query : {
              wildcard: {
                name: '*' + req.query.name + '*'
            }
          },
          highlight: {
              fields : {
                  display_name : {}
              }
          }
        }
      }).then(results => res.send(results), err => res.send(err));
      break;
      .....
      .....
```

Comment: Unrelated: You do not want to have a leading wildcard. It will crush your performance at scale (you're literally asking it to check every document for a match rather than without wildcards, which can skip).

Comment: Related: Which field is the one that breaks with the space? `class_id` or `name`?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that it breaks on name, I removed the filter query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like logstash handles this.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-1-3-1-released